# String won't reverse using reverse_copy

Tags: c++

If I have a string `A` that equals `"abc"` and I want to have string `B` that is the reversed form of string `A`, why can't I use `reverse_copy()` to do this ?

```
std::string A = "abc";
std::string B;

std::reverse_copy(A.begin(), A.end(), B.begin());

std::cout << B << std::endl;  // no output
```

Is `reverse_copy()` usable with strings? `reverse()` seems to work.

Comment: Ask yourself: How many elements are in `B` that you can write to.

Comment: FWIW, I think you missed a closing parenthesis on the third line.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The `string` you are trying to copy into is too short (zero length). You have to make it long enough to accept the copied data:

```
std::string A = "abc";
std::string B;
B.resize(A.size()); // make B big enough

std::reverse_copy(A.begin(), A.end(), B.begin());

std::cout << B << '\n';
```

Currently you are writing *past the end* of `B` causing *undefined behavior*.

Another way to do this is to use a special iterator called [`std::back_insert_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator), which pushes characters to the back of the target string:

```
std::string A = "abc";
std::string B;

std::reverse_copy(A.begin(), A.end(), std::back_inserter(B));
```

The [`std::back_inserter()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) function returns a [`std::back_insert_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator) for the string you provide as a parameter (or any container that implements `push_back()`, such as [`std::string::push_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/push_back)).

**Note:** [std::reverse_copy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse_copy) invoked with standard `std::string` iterators (as in this example) will simply reverse the *code units* of a string and not *necessarily* the characters (depending on the encoding). For example a `UTF-8` encoded string that contains multibyte characters would not be reversed correctly by this function as the multibyte sequences would also be reversed making them invalid.

Comment: Of course for this application (create a new string `B` that's the reverse of `A`), a simpler approach is to use `A`'s reverse iterators: `const std::string B(A.crbegin(), A.crend());`

Comment: Another caution is that these operations act on `char` units, not Unicode graphemes (assuming, say, UTF-8).  So if your string data contains "funny" characters, it may not work as desired.

Comment: [Various ways to reverse a `std::string`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55940377/65863)

Comment: @Eljay Thanks, I added your caution to the answer.

Answer (score 18):

`std::reverse_copy` doesn't allocate space, so your code leads to undefined behavior. Either allocate space beforehand:

```
string A = "abc";
string B;
B.resize(A.size());
reverse_copy(A.begin(),A.end(),B.begin());
cout<<B<<endl;
```

or use `std::back_inserter`:

```
string A = "abc";
string B;
reverse_copy(A.begin(),A.end(),std::back_inserter(B));
cout<<B<<endl;
```

Answer (score 9):

`std::reverse_copy` expects there to be pre-allocated space in the destination, so you want something like:

```
std::string a = "abc";
std::string b(a.size(), ' ');
std::reverse_copy(std::begin(a), std::end(a), std::begin(b);
std::cout << b << "\n";
```