# The function returns empty string

Tags: c++, string

in the following code `reverse` function rerturns an empty string. no compilation errors.

what can cause the problem here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/basic_string.h>
using namespace std;

string reverse(string str) { 
    string r;

    for (int i=str.length()-1; i>=0; i--) {
        r[str.length() - 1 - i] = str[i];  
    }

    return r;
} 

int main() {
    string str = "ABCDefgh";

    cout<<"Reverse string is : "<<reverse(str)<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Edit:
<strike>r[str.length() - i] = str[i];</strike>  
r[str.length() - 1 - i] = str[i];

Comment: you need to allocate space for `r`, its length is 0.

Comment: Why `<bits/basic_string.h>` instead of `<string>`?

Comment: _"no compilation errors ... `r[str.length() - i] = str[i];`"_ is _undefined behavior_.

Comment: It works fine after allocating length.   Do I always need to declare length for a string? Will string behave differently in c++ than it behaves in php or javascript?

Comment: @ShivCKushawah _"Will string behave differently in c++ than it behaves in php or javascript?"_ Yes. None of the c++ containers supports automatic resizing.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ None of the standard sequential containers support automatically inserting for out of bounds accesses, but associative containers (like `std::map`) do.

Comment: At last not automated in that fashion. Various push and remove functions and assignments will resize the underlying buffer. `std::back_inserter` is another useful tool.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux OK, good nitpick :)

Comment: I'm going a bit further than Quimby. Don't include anything from the bits folder. Everything in bits is implementation-specific and intended to be included from a higher-level header. The implementation details can change without warning and are not the same, likely they don't even exist, across all C++ implementations. Without being included by the higher-level header, the headers in bits may malfunction because some set-up that's assumed to have been performed by the higher-level header may not have been performed.

Comment: Why don't you just use [std::reverse](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse)?

Comment: @Jesper Juhl Tried to do it myself

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your function is invoking UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR, as you are not allocating any memory for the `r` string before using its `[]` operator to assign characters to `r`.  [`std::string::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) does not perform any bounds checking, so you are actually trashing surrounding memory.  Also, you are not indexing into `r` correctly, too (your indexing is off by 1).

Had you used the [`std::string::at()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at) method instead of the `operator[]`, it would have raised a runtime exception complaining about you accessing characters out of bounds.

You need to make a *copy* of the input `str` first, and then you can reverse the characters of that copy, eg:

```
std::string reverse(std::string str) { 
    std::string r = str; // <-- COPY HERE

    for (int i = str.length()-1, j = 0; i >= 0; --i, ++j) {
        r[j] = str[i];  
    }

    return r;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`std::string::resize()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize) method to pre-allocate the `r` string, then use of `operator[]` will be valid:

```
std::string reverse(std::string str) { 
    std::string r;
    r.resize(str.length()); // <-- ALLOCATE HERE

    for (int i = str.length()-1, j = 0; i >= 0; --i, ++j) {
        r[j] = str[i];  
    }

    return r;
}
```

Or, you can use the [`std::string::push_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/push_back) method instead (optionally with the [`std::string::reserve()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/reserve) method to avoid re-allocations while pushing):

```
std::string reverse(std::string str) { 
    std::string r;
    r.reserve(str.length()); // <-- OPTIONAL

    for (int i = str.length()-1; i >= 0; --i) {
        r.push_back(str[i]);  
    }

    return r;
}
```

Or, have a look at replacing your manual loop with the [`std::reverse_copy()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse_copy) algorithm instead:

```
#include <algorithm>

std::string reverse(std::string str) { 
    std::string r;
    r.resize(str.length());
    std::reverse_copy(str.begin(), str.end(), r.begin());
    return r;
}
```

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

std::string reverse(std::string str) { 
    std::string r;
    r.reserve(str.length()); // <-- OPTIONAL
    std::reverse_copy(str.begin(), str.end(), std::back_inserter(r));
    return r;
}
```

However, that being said, since the input `str` is being passed *by value*, it is ALREADY a copy of whatever string you pass to your function, so you don't actually need the local `r` string at all.  You can reverse the characters of the input `str` in-place, just be use to take into account that the source and destination strings are the same string, so adjust your loop accordingly:

```
std::string reverse(std::string str) { 
    int count = str.length() / 2;
    for (int i = 0, j = str.length()-1; i < count; ++i, --j) {
        char ch = str[i];
        str[i] = str[j];
        str[j] = ch;

        // alternatively:
        // std::swap(str[i], str[j]);
    }

    return str;
}
```

Or, have a look at the [`std::reverse()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) algorithm instead:

```
#include <algorithm>

std::string reverse(std::string str) { 
    std::reverse(str.begin(), str.end());
    return str;
}
```

Or, you can use the `std::string` constructor that takes 2 iterators as input, as `std::string` has [reverse iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator) available:

```
std::string reverse(std::string str) { 
    return std::string(str.rbegin(), str.rend());
}
```

Comment: Well this is pass by value, so you don't even need to make a copy - you already have one.

Comment: You do not even need `std::reverse()` just one liner `return std::string( str.rbegin(), str.rend() );` will do